# Bibdesk import article information

Tags: bibliographies, mactex, bibdesk

I am working on my thesis and this includes a number of articles downloaded from various academic resources.

When doing this hardly any citation information is coming along with the papers and i have manually update the information for my bibliography to be upto date.

Are there any suggestions on how to improve and have bibdesk 'fetch' this information for me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) No need to add thanks or signature. your user badge is automaticaly inserted in your post and you can simply upvote any good answers you receive to show your appreciation.

Comment: Try the [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/) reference manager. It's a browser plugin which downloads all the metadata together with the articles.

Comment: @wierts Well, Zotero is a full-fledged reference manager. It's a replacement for bibdesk. Zotero stores all files and data in some directory or online, you can certainly drag-and-drop pdfs to bibdesk, but that's inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

For my thesis, I used Mendeley.  Really liked it as there is a desktop client that syncs with a web-based one. Further, there is a Microsoft plugin to get at your bib (though I never use Word, that is handy).  Also, for many PDFs it does a good job of auto-populating many of the fields.  Once you're done, you can just export your bib file to your LaTex directory.  Very handy.